# ng-required not working when submitting a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-forms

I have the following code in an input text box with the required attribute, but when I tab off of the field or submit the form, it doesn't stop the form from submitting and informing the user the field is required.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
   <input type="text" ng-required="true" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter Total Amount" id="txtTotalAmount" 
    ng-model="formCtrl.AddCheckDeposit.TotalAmount" />
</div>
```

What do I need to do to make the required directive to work?

Answer (score 4):

For that you should fire `ng-submit` event when form is valid

```
ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submit()"
```

Seems like you have also missed the `name` attribute on your input field, also for showing an error you could use `ng-show`/`ng-messages` directive

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submit()">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" ng-required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total Amount" name="txtTotalAmount"
       id="txtTotalAmount" ng-model="formCtrl.AddCheckDeposit.TotalAmount" />
      <span ng-show="myForm.txtTotalAmount.$error.required">Required</span>
   </div>  
</form>
```