# Cannot get form validation to work with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am simply trying to get a validation message to appear on a form either when it is submitted or when the user tabs to another field.

I have the following code in place (with a "novalidate" attribute on the masterpage form tag), but cannot get it to work.

Does anybody have any ideas how this simple validation should be able to work with Angular?

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Check Slip Number" id="txtCDDepositSlipNumber" name="txtCDDepositSlipNumber" ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedSlipID" required />
</div>
<div role="alert">
  <span class="error" ng-show="form1.txtCDDepositSlipNumber.$error.required">Required!</span>
</div>
```

### EDIT

Entire code base where the plunker doesn't work. If somebody can notice something that is causing it not to work, I would very much appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="ryder-warranty">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta name="description" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /><title>

</title><link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /><link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link rel="../content/lib/assets/css/ace-skins.min.css" /><link rel="../content/lib/assets/css/ace-rtl.min.css" /><link href="../Content/lib/assets/css/js-css-menu.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../Content/sweet-alert/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />






    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.debug.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ryder/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ryder/hidden-navs.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/grid.locale-en.min.js"></script>


    <script src="/Content/lib/assets/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Content/lib/assets/js/bootbox3/bootbox.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/Common.js"></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/AnnualGoal.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/MonthlyGoal.js'></script>

    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/CheckEntry.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/CreditSourceDocs.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/StopPenalize.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/PISIQueue.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/BalanceReview.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/StopPenalizePI.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/StopPenalizeAI.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/WorkQueueSummary.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/AppealTransmissionLog.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/OtherDeptsTransfer.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/LocationsTransfer.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/ImportRebuildClaims.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/JournalVoucher.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/CreditMemo.js'></script>

    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/DupUnIdentResponses.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/CreditQueue.js'></script>

    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/ReversePenalize.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/CheckDeposit.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/DataServices/Escalation.js'></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/AccountingModule/Common.js'></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style3 {
            left: 0px;
            top: 7px;
        }
    </style>



    <link href="../Content/bootswatch.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../Content/jasny-bootstrap/jasny-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../Content/angular-ui/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../Content/assets/css/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../Content/assets/css/bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" /><link href="../Content/ryder_web.css" rel="stylesheet" />






    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jasney-bootstrap/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/monent-js/monent.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/sweet-alert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.min.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/angular/angular-1.4.5.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <script src='/Scripts/showErrors.js'></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-0.13.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-controllers/ryder-module.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mike-marcacci/objectpath/v1.1.0/lib/ObjectPath.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geraintluff/tv4/v1.1.9/tv4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/0.8.0/dist/schema-form.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/0.8.0/dist/bootstrap-decorator.js"></script>

    <script>
        var root = '/';
        //console.log("root: " + root);
    </script>


</head>
<body style="background-color: #cfc9c9">
    <form method="post" action="CheckDepositProcess.aspx" id="form1" novalidate="">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="vcFExEZBEsQiDCkCSBU+2n/tQOoFbgoHH52LZBSuwmbbQPBteWfSaTizqamROXGuQI9IyxJq5XH+2fN5mauU+WINo9+rqaB9DX6l2nufy34=" />
</div>

        <div class="container">

            <!-- Static navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle nav-left" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#navbar" data-canvas="body" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img src="../Images/ryder/ryder-logo.png" alt="icon" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-156" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-offcanvas offcanvas navmenu-fixed-left">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Accounting<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href='CreditMemo.aspx'>Credit Memo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='UnidentifiedClaimResponse.aspx'>UnIdentified. Responses</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='CheckEntry.aspx'>Check Entry</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a tabindex="-1" href='javascript: void(0)'>CSD Spreadsheet Import</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href='ImportCreditSourceDocs.aspx'>Credit Memo Import</a></li>
                                            <li><a href='#'>Check Import</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href='CheckDepositProcess.aspx'>Check Deposit</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='ReversePenalize.aspx'>Reverse Penalize</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='AccountBalancingProcess.aspx'>Account Balancing</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a tabindex="-1" href='javascript: void(0)'>Journal Voucher</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href='JournalVoucher.aspx'>Journal Voucher List</a></li>
                                            <li><a href='LocationsTransfer.aspx'>Locations Transfer</a></li>
                                            <li><a href='OtherDeptsTransfer.aspx'>Other Dept Transfer</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>



                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Queue Management<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href='ManagementCreditQueue.aspx'>Management Credit Queue</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href='ManufacturerSetup.aspx'>Manufacturer Setup</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='EscalationParameterSetup.aspx'>Escalation Parameter Setup</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='PenalizationParameter.aspx'>Penalization Parameter Setup</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='VarianceReason.aspx'>Variance Reason</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='CrossRefToMFRVarianceReason.aspx'>Crossref to MFR Variance Reason</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='CurrencyConversion.aspx'>Currency Conversion</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='WarrantyLocations.aspx'>Warranty Locations</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='WarrantyGLAccounts.aspx'>Warranty General Ledger Accounts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='CorporateGLCrossReference.aspx'>Corporate GL Cross Reference</a></li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a tabindex="-1" href='javascript: void(0)'>User</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href='../Administration/Users.aspx'>Users
                                            </a></li>
                                            <li><a href='../Administration/Roles.aspx'>Roles
                                            </a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Maintain Goal<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href='GoalTypes.aspx'>Goal Types</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='CalendarSetup.aspx'>Calendar Setup</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='AnnualGoal.aspx'>Annual Goal</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='MonthlyGoal.aspx'>Monthly Goal</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Supporting Items<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href='RyderRepairs.aspx'>Ryder Repairs</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a tabindex="-1" href='#'>Claims</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href='RepairsClaim.aspx'>Repair Claims</a></li>
                                            <li><a href='DealerClaim.aspx'>Dealer Claims</a></li>
                                            <li><a href='SupplierClaim.aspx'>Supplier Claims</a></li>  
                                            <li><a href='ClaimStatusVIew.aspx'>Claim Status View</a></li>             
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="ImportRebuildClaims.aspx">Import Rebuild Claims</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a tabindex="-1" href='#'>Warranty Tracking</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href='Escalation.aspx'>Shipping</a></li>
                                            <li><a href='Escalation.aspx'>Additional info</a></li>
                                            <li><a href='Escalation.aspx'>Picture</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>



                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!--/.container-fluid -->
            </nav>

        </div>

        <div class="content-body">


    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-home home-icon"></i>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Accounting</a></li>
        <li class="active">Check Deposit</li>
    </ol>

    <div ng-controller="CheckDepositProcessFormController as formCtrl">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Check Deposit</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="control-label align-left">Check Slip Number:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Check Slip Number" id="txtCDDepositSlipNumber" name="txtCDDepositSlipNumber" ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedSlipID" required />
                            </div>
                            <div role="alert">
                                <span class="error" ng-show="form1.txtCDDepositSlipNumber.$error.required">Required!</span>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="control-label align-left">Country Code:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <select class="form-control"
                                    id="ddlCDWarLocation" required
                                    ng-init="formCtrl.getWarrantyLocation('/OptionList/GetWarrantyLocationDataAsync')"
                                    ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedWarrantyLocation"
                                    ng-options="item.Value as item.Text for item in formCtrl.listWarrantyLocation">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="control-label align-left">Posted Date:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label class="control-label align-left">From</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dteCDDateSubmittedFromGL" ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedDatePostedFromGL" ng-init="formCtrl.datePickerConfig.jqueryDatePicker('#dteCDDateSubmittedFromGL')" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label class="control-label align-left">To</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dteCDDatePostedToGL" ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedDatePostedToGL" ng-init="formCtrl.datePickerConfig.jqueryDatePicker('#dteCDDatePostedToGL')" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="control-label align-left">Deposit Slip Status:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <select class="form-control"
                                    id="ddlCDSlipStatus" required
                                    ng-init="formCtrl.getDepositSlipStatus('/OptionList/GetDepositSlipStatusDataAsync')"
                                    ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedDepositSlipStatus"
                                    ng-options="item.Value as item.Text for item in formCtrl.listDepositSlipStatus">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="control-label align-left">JVNumber:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter JV Number" id="txtJournalVoucherID" ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedJournalVoucherID" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="control-label align-left">Deposit Slip Amount:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Deposit Slip Amount" id="txtDepositSlipAmount" ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedSlipAmount" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="CheckDepositProcessGridController as gridCtrl">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnNew" ng-click="formCtrl.newCheckDeposit()">New</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                        <button type="Reset" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="formCtrl.setReset()" id="btnCDClear">Clear</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCDSearch" ng-click="gridCtrl.getGridData('/CheckDepositProcess/GetCheckDepositProcessDataAsync', formCtrl.depositSlip)">Search</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridCtrl.gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-controller="AlertCtrl">
                <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts" ng-show="alert.show">
                    <alert type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
                </div>
                <button class='btn' ng-click="addAlert()">Deposit Slip Saved</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-controllers/check-deposit.js"></script>

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT # 2 - Input box
--------   ---------

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total Amount" id="txtTotalAmount" name="txtTotalAmount" ng-model="formCtrl.AddCheckDeposit.TotalAmount" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="help-block" ng-if="userForm.txtTotalAmount.$error.required">Required</p>
```

### mASTERPAGE:

```
<form id="userForm" name="userForm" novalidate>
```

Comment: you didn't post the entire form, you only posted a single element from the form, so it's not really obvious if you are missing an element or have something else wrong here.

Comment: ??? don't understand...

Comment: what's not to understand? you didn't provide a [mcve], so there isn't enough information here for anyone to do anything more than just guess at what might be the problem, as the only answer here which you already shut down points at.

Comment: besides the fact that it looks like you already asked essentially the same question, with basically the same issue of missing details.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001589/ng-required-not-working-when-submitting-a-form

Comment: The above is a code snippet for one item I have in my form. There is no point including the whole form since it would just get anyone confused. The above code snippet is the only one that is dealing with the Angular verification.  I also modified the form for the second div, but still can't get it to work; thus the need for another question.

Comment: but you haven't included the `<form>` tag, which means that ***the specific framework feature you are asking about will not work with the code as provided.***.  There is no way for us to know if your form tag is missing, or mangled, or doesn't have the name correct, or thousands of other possibilities.

Comment: In my original message, I stated the following: I have the following code in place (with a "novalidate" attribute on the masterpage form tag), but cannot get it to work. I will try and put more info (via an Edit) once I can post it.

Comment: to illustrate this more clearly, I did in the last two minutes set up a plunker in which I took the suggestion from the answer (add a `<form>` tag) and pasted your element, and it functions as expected.  http://plnkr.co/edit/enVByxUBT0dKS0oghbgg?p=preview  If your code does not work, you have something else in your code interfering.

Comment: Claies, thanks for the plunker... I created another one at the following. http://plnkr.co/edit/5NB9FTAuHhHDNsjdsCSK but won't do much good as all it will show is the main menu. If you could recognize what might be wrong with this whole code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: well, to start with, angular won't work with `'angular' is undefined` errors in the console....

Comment: Claies, based on the documentation, I have written the code in my EDIT # 2 update. I'm expecting the form to not be submitted and the error message to show up. However, the error msg doesn't show up and the form continues to be submitted. Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong in the Edit # 2 validation?

Comment: Well, your form is not a form

Answer (score 0):

please wrap your code with that tag:

```
<form name="form1">
```

Comment: don't forget to add novalidate, so you disable the browser validation avoiding problems

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for angular validation alerts in one of my project.
So here is your solution that will surely work for your code. below is the code:

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="formName.inpuTagName.$dirty && formName.inpuTagName.$invalid">Required</span> //
```

I think In your case form name is "userForm" in which you want to show the alert for the input tag named "txtCDDepositSlipNumber".